# Move multiple files for different folders using Make

Tags: bash, shell, makefile, sh, gnu-make

Have two files, namely pyproject.toml and poetry.lock which is located in a folder called **dump**. I want to move those files to 2 directories for when running tests.

Today I do thise

```
PROJECT_DIR := $(realpath $(CURDIR))
BUILD_DUMP_DIR := $(PROJECT_DIR)/dump
DESTINATION_DIRS := unit system endtoend

PY_SOURCES = $(patsubst %,$(BUILD_DUMP_DIR)/%, pyproject.toml)
POETRY_SOURCES = $(patsubst %,$(BUILD_DUMP_DIR)/%, poetry.lock)

PY_PROJECT = $(foreach dir, $(DESTINATION_DIRS), $(patsubst %, $(BUILD_DUMP_DIR)/tests/$(dir)/%, pyproject.toml))
POETRY_PROJECT = $(foreach dir, $(DESTINATION_DIRS), $(patsubst %, $(BUILD_DUMP_DIR)/tests/$(dir)/%, poetry.lock))

$(PY_PROJECT): $(PY_SOURCES)
    @echo "=> Moving $< to $@"
    @cp $< $@

$(POETRY_PROJECT): $(POETRY_SOURCES)
    @echo "=> Moving $< to $@"
    @cp $< $@

copy-dump: $(PY_PROJECT) $(POETRY_PROJECT)
```

so running **make copy-dump** will move those files to the specified directory. Realize there must be nicer MakeFile command to do this. Thanks for all input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I understood all details but if you use GNU make and you want to copy (not move) your 2 files to 3 different locations each, the following is a bit simpler:

```
PROJECT_DIR := $(realpath $(CURDIR))
BUILD_DUMP_DIR := $(PROJECT_DIR)/dump
DESTINATION_DIRS := unit system endtoend

PY_SOURCES = $(BUILD_DUMP_DIR)/pyproject.toml
POETRY_SOURCES = $(BUILD_DUMP_DIR)/poetry.lock

PY_PROJECT = $(patsubst %,$(BUILD_DUMP_DIR)/tests/%/pyproject.toml,$(DESTINATION_DIRS))
POETRY_PROJECT = $(patsubst %,$(BUILD_DUMP_DIR)/tests/%/poetry.lock,$(DESTINATION_DIRS))

.PHONY: copy-dump
copy-dump: $(PY_PROJECT) $(POETRY_PROJECT)

.SECONDEXPANSION:

$(PY_PROJECT) $(POETRY_PROJECT): $(BUILD_DUMP_DIR)/$$(notdir $$@)
    @echo "=> Moving $< to $@"
    @cp $< $@
```

See [the GNU make documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Secondary-Expansion) for the details about secondary expansion.

Comment: Nice with SECONDEXPANSION thanks